# Could not load content1.png asset as non content file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, monogame

When trying to import an image into my 'game' I get a error message. The one displayed in the title. it is called content1.png and is in the Content folder. I have

```
public override void LoadContent()
{
    base.LoadContent();
    path = "Content/content1.png";
    splash1 = content.Load<Texture2D>(path);
}
```

and it doesn't load it.
I have no idea what to do here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's seems like the `content.Load<Texture2D>` method tries to open the file from your File-System and it is not founded there, do the following to solve it:

In Visual Studio -> Right-Click on the `content1.png` file -> Select Properties ->

- Set the **Build-Action** to `"Content"` in the properties window for
  `content1.png`.
- Set the **Copy to Output Directory** to -> `Always`

Comment: Thank you, is there any way I can automatically put images to Always? Because I'm lazy. Doesn't matter if there isn't tough.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted solution didn't work for me, I finally figured out that it was the relative path of the asset that was creating problems, so changing

```
Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics\\MyAsset.png")
```

to

```
Content.Load<Texture2D>("..\\Graphics\\MyAsset.png")
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: The latest monogame updates are driving me nuts... I have Monogame 3.5 on Xamarin, and now none of my content files want to load anymore. They did load on version 3.4. The properties of the file are set to 'content', but I still get the error "Could not load as a non-content file"....

Answer (score 1):

In **MonoGame 3.5.1** you must use **MonoGame pipeline tool** for your resources, and include builded ***.mgcb** file to your content folder in project. See sample project Platformer2d.

> MonoGame pipeline tool
>   http://www.monogame.net/2016/03/17/monogame-3-5/
>
> Samples https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame.Samples